# How do I insert data into an ACF-field with an Ajax POST in a Wordpress JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

**What I'm working in**: Wordpress with ACF plugin and JavaScript.

**What I'm trying to do**: create a post and set the title, content, status and some ACF-fields.

**What is output**: It successfully creates the post, but only sets the title and content. The ACF-fields are blank.

**What alternatives I have tried**: tried changing 'acf_fields:' to 'fields:' with no luck.

**Question**: Am I using the wrong label for ACF-fields? Or is there another way of doing this?

```
  createMarker(latitude, longitude) {
    var ourNewPost = {
      title: latitude + ", " + longitude,
      content: "Coordinates: " + latitude + ", " + longitude,
      status: "publish",
      acf_fields: {
        points_title: "test",
        points_latitude: latitude.toString(),
        points_longitude: longitude.toString(),
        status: 0
      },
    };

    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: (xhr) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-WP-Nonce", myData.nonce);
      },
      url: myData.root_url + "/wp-json/wp/v2/points/",
      type: "POST",
      data: ourNewPost,
      success: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      },
    });
  }
```

Defining my custom post-type:

```
function points(){
  register_post_type('points', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor','custom-fields'),
    'show_ui' => true,

    'public' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Points'
    )
  ));

}
add_action('init', 'points');
```

Comment: Have you made the meta fields available to update via the REST API? The API also has some finicky rules with how the request has to be structured to update those meta fields, so you may need to check the docs on this: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/

Comment: I've updated to show how I define the post type in question. Here i set 'show_in_rest' => true. This should make the post type itself publicly available to the rest api, right? Is this what you mean?

Comment: @jeffmayn no - you need to make the actual field group in ACF available to the REST API. Make sure your [field groups are enabled](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/#enabling-the-rest-api-for-your-acf-fields).

Comment: Ah, yeah, those are enabled too. Still no effect on my current code implementation

Comment: Also, if you look at the data structure the POST is expecting, it's `acf` not `fields` or `acf_fields`

Comment: Thaaanks, that was it!

Comment: @disinfor if you write it as an answer I will accept it as the answer to my question

Comment: @jeffmayn done. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `CreateMarker` function. The object field key for the ACF fields is incorrect - it should simply be: `acf`

```
createMarker(latitude, longitude) {
    var ourNewPost = {
      title: latitude + ", " + longitude,
      content: "Coordinates: " + latitude + ", " + longitude,
      status: "publish",
      acf: {
        points_title: "test",
        points_latitude: latitude.toString(),
        points_longitude: longitude.toString(),
        status: 0
      },
    };
```

Here's the [documentation link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wp-rest-api-integration/#request-methods) which shows the entire `POST` fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call hook when post save and then you can write your code in hook to fill acf field data.

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'set_acf_data');

function set_acf_data($post_id)
{
  
  $acf_data= "Your Data which you want to add in ACF field";

  if ('post' == get_post_type($post_id)) {

    update_field('acf_key', $acf_data, $post_id);

  }
}
```

Comment: I add this to functions.php, right? How do I call the hook from the ajax call?

Comment: Hook will call automatically when you save post, No need to call with ajax.

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work. How do i read the, lets say, points_title from the ajax call in this hook?